# Module 'jest-junit' in the testResultsProcessor option was not found

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have setup `jest` and `jest-junit` as the reporter and followed the simple instructions given by jest-junit.

This includes `npm install jest --save-dev` and  `npm install jest-junit --save-dev`

My `package.json` looks like this (excerpt):

```
  "devDependencies": { 
    "jest": "^22.4.4",
    "jest-junit": "^4.0.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --ci --testResultsProcessor='jest-junit'"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-junit"
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "suiteName": "Test Suite",
    "output": "./junit.xml"
  }
```

When running `npm run test` on my machine (OSX), it works well. When running it as part of the CI build process or on another Windows machine, I am getting the following error:

Module 'jest-junit' in the testResultsProcessor option was not found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution and it was the removal of inverted commas.

```
"test": "jest --ci --testResultsProcessor='jest-junit'"
```

should become

```
"test": "jest --ci --testResultsProcessor=jest-junit"
```

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you just need to install the missing module to the other machine:

```
npm install jest-junit
```

Comment: Edited original question. Included `jest-junit` as a devDependency and run `npm install` (without error) prior to running `npm run test`

Comment: In my case it's worked fine with `yarn add jest-junit` ...